# ejabberd muc room chat history

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

Each time a new user connects to the MUC room he does not recieve previously sent message history. I want to be able to allow all users that join my MUC room to see past message history. How to do this?

Comment: history is sent only to the first newly joined user into the room. the rest of the users that join do not recieve message history at all. client is gajim v1.0.3.

Comment: seems problem with the client (gajim). tested it with conversations and it's receiving all history for users.

Comment: now does anyone know how to fix the problem with gajim regarding this?